# Headless Firefox and Selenium

Tags: firefox, selenium

i try to run Selenium code with headless firefox. In Eclipse i put this code:

```
String Xport = System.getProperty(
            "lmportal.xvfb.id", ":10");
    final File firefoxPath = new File(System.getProperty(
            "lmportal.deploy.firefox.path", "/usr/bin/firefox/"));
    FirefoxBinary firefoxBinary = new FirefoxBinary(firefoxPath);
    firefoxBinary.setEnvironmentProperty("DISPLAY", Xport);

    // Start Firefox driver
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxBinary, null);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

But when arrive at:

```
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxBinary, null);
```

does not go forward..

I try to use phantomjs but is very very slow..

Comment: There is also a headless version of Chrome.  I have heard of it and so I know it exists.

Comment: as far as i know, you cannot use headless firefox.  Firefox, in itself, is a physical browser.  It's an oxymoron to say, "load up this browser, but make it headless"

Comment: @sircapsalot, nah, you can do it. The point is to run firefox in the X Virtual Framebuffer, like it is being done here. Anyway, back to the question - are you sure you have that X Server started? Can you start up firefox in using export 'DISPLAY=:10 && firefox' ?

Comment: @sircapsalot : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb , it is basically x server, that has virtual display in memory without any hardware or drivers.

Comment: typo in the first comment, i meant `export DISPLAY=:10 && firefox`

Answer (score 0):

yes. you may run selenium with headless firefox via Xvbf. you may have below steps to have it:

- Install Xvbf like **yum install xorg-x11-server-Xvfb.x86_64**
- start Xvbf and set DISPLAY number  **nohup Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1024x768x24  &**
- And in your code, it may be like

  FirefoxBinary firefoxBinary = new FirefoxBinary(firefoxPath);
   firefoxBinary.setEnvironmentProperty("DISPLAY", 1);